# sqlalchemy column_property in func count

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, command-line-interface

So I am new to python and sqlalchemy, I have been following this extended learning moudle and when I ran the pyhton3 seeds.py I keep getting this error. I need help understanding the error please and thank you!

in _raise_for_expected
raise exc.ArgumentError(msg, code=code) from err
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.count at 0x105d49400; count>]. Did you mean to say select(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.count at 0x105d49400; count>)?

```
For the Post.py

from datetime import datetime
from app.db import Base
from .Vote import Vote
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, DateTime, select, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, column_property


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    post_url = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)

    vote_count = column_property(
        select([func.count(Vote.id)]).where(Vote.post_id == id)
    )
    votes = relationship("Vote", cascade="all,delete")

    comments = relationship("Comment", cascade="all,delete")

    user = relationship("User")
```

for the Vote.py

```
from app.db import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey

class Vote(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'votes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('posts.id'))
```

for the User.py

```
import bcrypt

from app.db import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

salt = bcrypt.gensalt()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

    @validates("password")
    def validate_password(self, key, password):
        assert len(password) > 4

        return bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode("utf-8"), salt)

    @validates("email")
    def validate_email(self, key, email):
        # make sure email address contains @ character
        assert "@" in email

        return email

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode("utf-8"), self.password.encode("utf-8"))
```

for the Comment.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from app.db import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "comments"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment_text = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)

    user = relationship("User")
```

and then lastly the seeds.py

```
from app.models import User
from app.db import Session, Base, engine
from app.models import User, Post, Comment, Vote

# drop and rebuild tables
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

db = Session()

# insert users
db.add_all([
  User(username='alesmonde0', email='nwestnedge0@cbc.ca', password='password123'),
  User(username='jwilloughway1', email='rmebes1@sogou.com', password='password123'),
  User(username='iboddam2', email='cstoneman2@last.fm', password='password123'),
  User(username='dstanmer3', email='ihellier3@goo.ne.jp', password='password123'),
  User(username='djiri4', email='gmidgley4@weather.com', password='password123')
])

db.commit()

# insert posts
db.add_all([
  Post(title='Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum', post_url='https://buzzfeed.com/in/imperdiet/et/commodo/vulputate.png', user_id=1),
  Post(title='Morbi non quam nec dui luctus rutrum', post_url='https://nasa.gov/donec.json', user_id=1),
  Post(title='Donec diam neque, vestibulum eget, vulputate ut, ultrices vel, augue', post_url='https://europa.eu/parturient/montes/nascetur/ridiculus/mus/etiam/vel.aspx', user_id=2),
  Post(title='Nunc purus', post_url='http://desdev.cn/enim/blandit/mi.jpg', user_id=3),
  Post(title='Pellentesque eget nunc', post_url='http://google.ca/nam/nulla/integer.aspx', user_id=4)
])

db.commit()

# insert comments
db.add_all([
  Comment(comment_text='Nunc rhoncus dui vel sem.', user_id=1, post_id=2),
  Comment(comment_text='Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est.', user_id=1, post_id=3),
  Comment(comment_text='Aliquam erat volutpat. In congue.', user_id=2, post_id=1),
  Comment(comment_text='Quisque arcu libero, rutrum ac, lobortis vel, dapibus at, diam.', user_id=2, post_id=3),
  Comment(comment_text='In hac habitasse platea dictumst.', user_id=3, post_id=3)
])

db.commit()

# insert votes
db.add_all([
  Vote(user_id=1, post_id=2),
  Vote(user_id=1, post_id=4),
  Vote(user_id=2, post_id=4),
  Vote(user_id=3, post_id=4),
  Vote(user_id=4, post_id=2)
])

db.commit()

db.close()
```

Comment: have you tried `column_property(select(func.count(Vote.id)).where(Vote.post_id == id))`?

Comment: Yes, that's what the module had me learned. vote_count = column_property(select(func.count(Vote.id)).where(Vote.post_id == id))

Comment: Oh, my bad, you took the array brackets off. It worked!! Thank you so much! Could you explain the difference to me, if you don't mind?